# can't download steam, need help with 403 error code

Tags: error-handling

when I try to download steam it sends me to a page that says,You don't have permission to access /steam/archive/precise/steam_latest.deb on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at repo.steamstatic.com Port 80, what do I do to download steam, if you could help me that would be awesome.

Comment: We can't fix this - this is an issue with Steam's stuff.  I would suggest trying `sudo apt-get install steam`.  Note though I would also assume that Precise is pretty old - they may not support it any more.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the link on [their page](http://store.steampowered.com/about/) is broken for me as well. Try opening a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and running `sudo apt-get install steam`.